# If velocity is relative, why mass (inertia) is increasing absolutely?

Tags: mass, velocity

Would inertia not grow if we took out the reference frame?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics, not astronomy. I'd recommend moving it to [Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/), if you can clarify what you mean by "took out the reference frame".

Comment: reference frame, here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVx5oraPWXk&t=2s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a conceptual thing: There's no 'taking out' the reference frame. Only changing it.
Next: Velocity $\dot x$ is the change of position $x$, thus this is a coordinate-dependent quantity.

Then mass is a bit more complicated, as there are two concepts of mass: **Inertial** mass and **gravitational** mass.
Inertial mass is the proportionality constant between an acting force $\vec F$ on a body and it's change of velocity $\ddot x$, thus we get Newton's 2nd law that states $\vec F = m \ddot x$. Thus inertial mass is coordinate-independent by construction. Similar for the gravitational mass.
Then experiments show that inertial and gravitational mass are equal, also there are [theoretical reasons to believe this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) Thus we can show that mass in total is coordinate independent.